# EF Core 1:1 Relation?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The tables i want are looking like this...

```
Identity  | Id (PK), Tag
Character | IdentityId (FK, PK), Health
```

The character table should reference exactly one single row of the identity table... and the identity table should not reference anything else 1:0.

My current model is looking like this...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an identity in our database. 
    /// </summary>
    public class Identity {

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an character ingame with all his attributes. 
    /// </summary>
    public class Character {
        
        public Identity Identity { get; set; }

        public float Health { get; set; }
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Identity>(entity => {

          entity.ToTable("identity");
          entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    });
            
     modelBuilder.Entity<Character>(entity => {

          entity.ToTable("character");
          // entity.HasKey(e -> e.Identity.Id); DOES NOT WORK
          entity.Navigation(character => character.Identity).AutoInclude();
     });
```

The problem with this is that the reference to the identity inside the character does not count as an primary key... neither a foreign key.

`e -> e.Identity.Id` does not work for some reason and results in an error telling me that this is not possible.

I want that the `Identity` inside the Character counts as his primary key, while still being a reference to an row inside the Identity-Table ( Foreign key ). The identity table however should not reference the character.

Is this possible ? If so... how ?

Comment: There's no `1:0` relation. That's 1:1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How is this type of relation called then ? :o i thought its 1:0... if not i need to edit my  title

Comment: That's a 1:1 relation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But the identity should not and does not refer the character... so is it really a 1:1 relation ?

Comment: Don't both database fields have the same value? `does not refer the character.` this has nothing to do with the fields in the classes. Relations are between tables, where there's no parent and child

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dont know what you mean... i just want that the character references the identity... and not that the identity also references the character back ( Which is 1:1 ).

Comment: This is an extention table and is a 1:1 reletion. 1:0 relation not exists

Comment: @Den Alright thanks ! :) Didnt knew that... however, how can we realise this ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure if I can follow you. Both in the class model and in the db model there can be an `Identity` without a matching `Character`. How is this 1:1? (And not 1:0..1, which is the more correct way to describe it, in a sense 1:0 doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a property in your Identity class

```
 public class Identity {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }

        public Character Character { get; set; }
    }
```

then your model become

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Identity>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Character)
                .WithOne(x => x.Identity)
                .HasForeignKey<Character>(x => x.YourFkKey);
```

Comment: `HasForeignKey` requires a generic type parameter to indicate which entity is dependent.

Comment: That's the wrong side. Identity is independent and Character.Id should be the FK. Which makes this a *shared primary key association*.